# Changing YouTrack 4.0.2 database location

Tags: linux

I've been using YouTrack 4.0 as a [standalone Linux service](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/YTD4/Linux.+YouTrack+JAR+as+a+Service) for several months and I decided recently to upgrade to the lastest version (4.0.2). Since I'm using the standalone approach, the upgrade is quite simple: 1) download last JAR, replace the symlink that was referenced in the `wrapper.conf` file.

I modified a bit that `wrapper.conf` to suit my environment:

```
wrapper.java.additional.11=-Dcatalina.base=%YOUTRACK_RUNTIME_DIR%/standalone
wrapper.java.additional.12=-Djetbrains.dnq.cachePercent=25
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Djetbrains.dnq.sharedCache=false
wrapper.java.additional.14=-Djetbains.webr.uiQueryCancellingPolicyTimeout=80000
wrapper.java.additional.15=-Djetbrains.dnq.fairLatches=false
wrapper.java.additional.16=-Djetbrains.dnq.readUncommittedForCachingThread=true
wrapper.java.additional.17=-Dyoutrack.http.port=%YOUTRACK_PORT%
wrapper.java.additional.18=-Dyoutrack.hostname=%YOUTRACK_IP%
wrapper.java.additional.19=-Dyoutrack.data.dir=%YOUTRACK_DATA_DIR%/standalone
```

**NOTE:** The `%YOUTRACK_DATA_DIR%` env var points to `/opt/local/var/db/youtrack`.

However when I started it I realized that it created a new database from scratch at `%YOUTRACK_HOME%`. It seems that this version can't understand the `youtrack.data.dir` system property.

Is there anyone that knows how to change the default database location in YouTrack 4.0.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out by myself when reading this [document](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/YTD4/Changing+Database+Location).

What I did was:

1. Uncompress `youtrack-4.0.2.jar` to a folder.
2. Go to `WEB-INF` and open the `web.xml` file
3. Replace the `${user.home}` references by `${youtract.data.dir}` ones
4. Repack the contents in the `youtrack-4.0.2.jar` and use that file to perform the installation.